# Receber dados de um site em uma aplicação JS - Phonegap

Tags: javascript, json, apache-cordova

É possível receber dados de um site mesmo eu não tendo acesso ao servidor dele?
Dei uma pesquisada e vi falarem do JSON mas pelo que me parece(posso estar equivocado, claro) só é possível implementa-lo através do proprio php no servidor então pra mim não adianta.
Gostaria de enviar e receber dados através do JS. Obrigado.

Comment: Consegue usando ajax

Comment: É possível utilizar JSON com JavaScript. Inclusive, tenho uma leve impressão que JSON significa JavaScript Son, enfim... apenas uma curiosidade.

Comment: O servidor a que te referes permite ir buscar dados? sabes o url para "pedir" dados?

Comment: @AndrewRibeiro JSON é "javascript object notation", pode pensar que é uma forma 'universal' de direntes linguagens comunicarem entre si. Não tem nada a haver com javascript sem ser a sintaxe que é muito parecida com a declaração de um obj em javascript

Comment: como assim pegar os dados de um servidor sem ter acesso a ele? Exemplifique para que possamos lhe ajudar

Comment: tipo galera, eu não administro o servidor php que quero acessar tenho somente acesso como cliente. Queria saber se existe uma forma de requisitar dados do site através do js. Um exemplo do que to falando é o app do Cartola Premiere que dá acesso ao Cartola FC. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cartola.premiere.pro&hl=pt_BR